# Install new gutters and leaders

Tags: gutters

After a new roof was installed, a different crew is coming over tomorrow to install new gutters and leaders.  Although they keep trying to sell me gutter guards, I said no, mostly after reading the answers in [What are my gutter guard options?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/what-are-my-gutter-guard-options) .

I will ask them to caulk the screw holes after they remove the old gutters and leaders.  I will also ask for swing-up elbows for to be installed where the downspouts touch the ground.  What else should I look out for?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/71591/43874).  Make sure they do any level to level transitions correctly.